# Find all consecutive repetition in a String java

Tags: java, string, dfa

I have to implement an algorithm to find all the consecutive repetitions in a String.

So, for example, given the String = `a a 1a a 1` generate a sort of regex like this `((a )+1)+`.

I was trying to apply a recursive algorithm but I didn't find nothing on the web. At the end it seems an implementation of a simple DFA.

Some help? Thanks.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Regex `(\b\w+\b)\s+((?:\s*\b\1\b)+)` might do it, where capture group 2 are the "consecutive repetitions", e.g. it captures the second `a` in your sample string. See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QHPLR9/1) for demo.

Comment: So what did you find?

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

### psueocode:

```
for every combination of two adjacent substrings of equal length
    if the two adjacent substrings are equal
        add the substring to a set of consecutive repetitions
```

### explanation:

The [`set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is important in order to avoid adding multiple instances of any particular consecutive repetition.  However, if that is what you want to do, then you could theoretically use any data structure.  (but a `multiset` would probably be best... see Google Guava's [`multiset`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html))

Note that the `for` loop iterates over every *combination*, not *permutation*.  This is because your problem statement implies that the order does not matter (is this true?).

Probably the easiest way to actually go about iterating through every combination of two adjacent substrings of equal length is to use two nested loops.  This step could be optimized as well (e.g. possibly with memoization).

---

---

## Example Code

```
for (int begin = 0; begin < string.length() - 1; ++begin) {
    for (int end = begin; end < (string.length() + begin) / 2; ++end) {

        substring_1 = string.substring(begin, end+1);
        substring_2 = string.substring(end+1, end+1 + substring_1.length());

        if (substring_1.equals(substring_2)) {
            set.add(substring_1);
        }
    }
}
```

Some notes about the example code:

- The `begin` and `end` indices are for `substring_1`.
- `substring_2` is the substring of equal length consecutive to `substring_1`.
- The `substring(int,int)` method includes the beginning index and excludes the ending index.  Hence the semantics above.
- The "begin" `for` loop does not include the very last index in the string.  This is because the non-empty substring that consists of the character at that index has no non-empty consecutive substring.
- The "end" `for` loop stops at the midpoint between `begin` and the end of the string.  This is because any substring that starts at `begin` and is longer than this has no consecutive substring of equal length.

### more optimizations:

- To avoid the overhead of generating two new String objects every iteration to represent substring_1 and substring_2, use the [`regionMatches(int,String,int,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#regionMatches-int-java.lang.String-int-int-) method instead.  Both the String that this method is invoked on as well as the "other" String argument will be the same (original, full length) String.

For example:

```
for (offset1 = 0; offset1 < string.length() - 1; ++offset1) {
    for (len = 1; len < ((string.length() - offset) / 2) + 1; ++len) {

        offset2 = offset1 + len;

        if (string.regionMatches(offset1, string, offset2, len)) {
            set.add(string.substring(offset1, offset1 + len));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you landed here from a google search and are looking for a java(script) solution here is the code
https://jsfiddle.net/xwem39sL/

Answer (score 0):

Start by dividing you String to character and then use a loop to check similarity :

```
String txt = "text";
char chars[] = txt.toCharArray();
for(int i =0; i < chars.length; i++){
    if(i>0){
        if(chars[i] == chars[i-1]) {
             System.out.println(i + " and" + (i-1) + "are similar");
        }
    }
}
```

that's just an example you can perfect it.

Comment: I believe the assignment is to find repetitions of space-separated *words*, not directly adjacent *characters*. Look at the example: `a a 1a a 1`. It has no repeated characters, but it does have a repeated word: `a`.

Comment: that's why i said :  **you can perfect it** and not **this is the final answer**

Comment: Writing something entirely different is not "perfecting it". Your code works on separate *characters* (`char`), but solution needs to work with *words* (`String`).

Comment: @Andreas and all you need to do is just replace array of char with array of string and slightly change comparison.

Comment: @talex It isn't "just" replacing `char[]` with `String[]`, now is it? The crux of the logic are these two lines: `char chars[] = txt.toCharArray();` and `if(chars[i] == chars[i-1]){`. Both of those *very critical* lines will be *entirely different*. It is not a `char[]`. You don't call `toCharArray()`. You can't use `==`.

Comment: Yes you need `txt.toCharArray()` if you want work with words not characters and I said "slightly change comparison" which cover problem with `==`. So I agree that it isn't exact solution to problem, but it is good point to start. It shows algorithm.